# Why cant I get proper sentence output?

Tags: c

Whats the problem on it..that I cant get that full sentence

> "even(variable) numbers are even".

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
    int i = 1, n = 0, even = 0, odd = 0;
    do{
        printf("Type in a Number-");
        scanf("%d", &n);
        if(n % 2 == 0)
            even = even + 1;
        else
            odd = odd + 1;
        i = i + 1;
    }
    while(i <= 10);
    printf("%d", even "numbers are even.");
    printf("%d", odd "numbers are odd.");
}
```

Comment: The problem is, this code doesn't *compile*. Ex: `printf("%d",even"numbers are even.");` should be `printf("%d numbers are even.\n", even);`

Comment: That's not how `printf()` works. Take a look at the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) please.

Comment: Next time, please copy/paste in the error messages from your compiler.  In this case, your problem is obvious, (you don't know how to use printf), but in other cases it amy be very important, (and you'll get downvoted anyway for a poor question, as here).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you only need to format your string correctly and the program will work:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int i = 1, n = 0, even = 0, odd = 0;
    do {
        printf("Type in a Number-");
        scanf("%d", &n);
        if (n % 2 == 0)
            even = even + 1;
        else
            odd = odd + 1;
        i = i + 1;
    } while (i <= 10);
    printf("%d numbers are even.", even);
    printf("%d numbers are odd.", odd);
    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have misunderstood the concept of printf statement.

This should be your code

```
printf("%d numbers are even.",even);
printf("%d numbers are odd.",odd);
```

See [documentation](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html) for printf or else `man printf` in UNIX.

Comment: What is the `</b>` for? With a missing space and no `newline`s this is careless.